# Django - shortcuts error

Tags: python, django

I'am just starting using Django.

I followed a tutorial for newbies but one think didn't run.

[Thetuttorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTNA0MtZwso)

This is my view code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Line
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
@render("story/home.html")
def home(request):
    return {'lines': Line.objects.all()}
```

This is the code from the base.html view:

```
{% extends "story/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for line in lines %}
<li style="color:{% cycle 'blue' 'green' %}">{{ line.text}}</li>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the error:

```
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'META'
```

I'm sorry if the error is very basic but i have any experience in Django and I'm trying to understand. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in that tutorial that in the view code return render to response: **context_instance=RequestContext(request)**

I suggest you not to worry about decorators if you are begining with Django, There are more important thinks to learn

Comment: Thanks budd, it was just like that!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed a few steps in that tutorial. You're using the render function from shortcuts as a decorator, but it isn't one. In that tutorial, he uses that function as the base for his own render decorator, and your missing that code.

(To be honest I'm not really sure why he does that, since to don't really gain anything, but maybe it's just as an example of how to write decorators - I haven't actually watched the video properly.)

Comment: You were right, it was a bit strange when he started to explain the shortcuts and write something but then deleted. I tried again and run ! I would like to vote you up because you were helpfull but I haven't enought points to do that, if you give me points in my question and I can thank you, I will do